# Javascript Kill function?

Tags: javascript

I have a rather simple javascript function that operates on keypress, checks to see if the key pressed is the enter key, builds a url and forwards the form using

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

This functions appropriately in IE, but errors in FireFox and (and possibly chrome).  It executes the code (or acts like it does), but something else is happening that prevents the change from taking place.

If I put an alert() immediately after that location redirect, that seems to kill all other code and my redirect does its thing.  However, presenting the visitor with an alert box even if they don't have to click it is tacky.  Attempts at using a timeout function have also failed.

Is there any way in regular old javascript to stop all other 
execution long enough for function to work.  I need the javascript equivalent of a php die(); (or whatever it is).  I'd like to get this working without having to rip the guts out of this site.

Comment: Isn't it just `window.location=url` ?

Comment: just look up "javascript die" and you'll find stuff like http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-124150.html

Comment: Maybe just throw an error with, uh... "throw", but could you show us your code so we can see why is this necessary?

Comment: You'd have to show us what is causing the problems after you set window.location.  The real answer is to fix those problems.  I don't know what's going on in the rest of your code, but maybe you need to stop propagation and/or prevent default handling of the the key event. You can't pause execution of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because of event bubbling? http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html describes the different ways browsers deal with events.